# Saving an object in the script

Tags: python, pickle

I have a list of objects created based on some data and would like to use those objects in another script.
To do this, I first pickled the object list using pickle.dump(filepath) to create a file on disk. Then, imported the objects using pickle.load(filepath) in the script. This works well.

Now I would like to distribute the script as exe file. exe created using pyinstaller --onefile myscript.py, still needs the external pickle file to load the objects.

Is there a way to embed the objects directly in the python script itself and not depend upon an external file?
pickle.dumps() creates a lot of lines to save it in the python file directly. Is there another way?

I am training a model (a machine learning model) based on some data in a python program. I would like to use the trained models in another script to avoid 1. training the every time and 2. to avoid giving away the training data to others. So, I saved the trained objects to a file using pickling

Comment: You don't need pickle if you're just storing objects directly in the script. Just declare the variables

Comment: The objects are created in a different script using some data and saved into a pickle file.
I cannot create objects in the same script, then it would need all data and training every time. Basically, I would like to embed the object directly in the script.

Comment: Then you should bundle multiple scripts together as a module or make your installer program first prompt and require an input file

Comment: Embedding pickled data instead of objects is pointless in my opinion. It defeats the purpose of pickling

Comment: Let me reword the question:
I am training a model (a machine learning model) based on some data in a python program. I would like to use the trained models in another script to avoid 1. training the every time and 2. to avoid giving away the training data to others. So, I saved the trained objects to a file using pickling.
In the installer program, I am using these objects using pickle.load. This would mean the file on disk is always needed (but I do not want to distribute the pickle file). How to avoid it? Is there  a way to embed objects directly in the installer program?

Comment: I understand the question fine, but I don't understand "it would need all data and training every time". If it needs that data anyway, what difference does it make if it is not pickled? Also, your exe should be able to package multiple files

Comment: You should be able to use the --add-binary <SRC;DEST or SRC:DEST> option to embed your pickles alongside the executable. https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#shortening-the-command

Comment: Yes, I am trying to use --add-binary. However, it creates a different folder everytime and it becomes hard to access the pickle file then...